# JavaScript to change onmouseover or onmouseout to call a different function?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

Is it possible to change a function that is called by an existing `onmouseover` or `onmouseout` event? For the following example is there a way for me to have `ChangeItemAEvent` change the "ItemA" `onmouseover` function from `ChangeColor()` to `ChangeColorBack()`? Currently I need to declare an entirely new function that I feel is not elegant because I am repeating code when I should be able to call an existing function.

javascript:

```
function ChangeColor(elementid)
{
  document.getElementById(elementid).style.background = "Orange";
  document.getElementById(elementid).style.color = "Black";
}

function ChangeColorBack(elementid)
{
  document.getElementById(elementid).style.background = "Black";
  document.getElementById(elementid).style.color = "White";
}

function ChangeItemAEvent()
{
  document.getElementById("ItemA").onmouseover = function() {

    document.getElementById("ItemA").style.background = "Black";
  document.getElementById("ItemA").style.color = "White";

  };
}
```

html:

```
<span id="ItemA" onmouseover="ChangeColor(this.id)">
<button id="ButtonB" onclick="ChangeItemAEvent()">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the events in JavaScript instead of in the markup:

```
document.getElementById('ItemA').onmouseover = changeColorBack;
```

Note that capitalized function names are usually reserved for constructors as a convention.
Then on your function use `this` which refers to the element where is being called:

```
function changeColorBack() {
  this.style.background = "Black";
  this.style.color = "White";
}
```

Now you can use these functions on any element by just assigning a new function to the element's event or by overriding the function that was previously set.

Comment: oh nice i addapted what you just said and this works for me now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a `toggleColor(elementId)` function:

```
function toggleColor(elementId) {
    if (this.style.color == "White") {
        this.style.background = "White";
        this.style.color = "Black";
    }else {
        this.style.background = "Black";
        this.style.color = "White";
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, except - use of elementId and this vars indicate an unfinished function. I.e you never call document.getElementById on the elementId - nor do you show the function being attached in a way that would render the 'this' keyword useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to do some reading on the different methods of registering events. It's important to note that there are 3 different methods for registering events in JavaScript. These are detailed at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event. Also note that the many different JavaScript frameworks add to this by providing their own methods for registering events in a cross-browser compatible way.

The method for setting events such as this `<button id="ButtonB" onclick="ChangeItemAEvent()">` in your example is not the recommended way for setting events. Neither is setting the `.onmouseover` or `.onclick` of the element.

I would recommend reading the link regarding events at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event), then if you're already using a JavaScript framework then read their documentation regarding events.

Also note there is a [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener) method that you may or may not find useful.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    function overBtn(btncalling) {
            document.getElementById(btncalling).style.backgroundColor = '#507CD1';
            document.getElementById(btncalling).style.color = 'White';
    }

    function outBtn(btncalling) {
            document.getElementById(btncalling).style.backgroundColor = 'White';
            document.getElementById(btncalling).style.color = '#507CD1';
    }
```